# New to scss, "rule is empty"?

Tags: sass

[see this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oCvGH/)

it is super basic

```
$span1Width:  10;
$marginWidth:  5;


@mixin span-width($spannr) {
      width: $span1Width   * $spannr *1%;
      *width: $marginWidth* $spannr -1 *1%;
}


div{
  @use span-width(10);
}
```

resulting in "empty rule" when doing a analyse css with codepen.

Comment: have you tried `@include` instead of `@use` ?

Comment: A quick check in the page source code should have shown you, that there stands `div{@use span-width(10);}` - so nothing happened to your code. This is due to the fact that you used an unknown keyword, like Fabrizio already explained.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the example on sass documentation on how to use mixins you can see:

```
$color: white;
@mixin colors($color: blue) {
  background-color: $color;
  @content;
  border-color: $color;
}

.colors {
  @include colors { color: $color; }
}
```

So you should use @include and { } instead. Like (using default 5 in this example):

```
$span1Width:  10;
$marginWidth:  5;


@mixin span-width($spannr: 5) {
      width: $span1Width   * $spannr *1%;
      *width: $marginWidth* $spannr -1 *1%;
}


div{
  @include span-width{ spannr: 10};
}
```

That should give you the correct result

Comment: I think there MUST be a whitespace between the operator and the number. E.g. `- 1 * 1%` not `-1 *1%`